# Why django is represented as a 'MTV' pattern?

Tags: django, model-view-controller

At the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names), they mention that

> In our interpretation of MVC, the “view” describes the data that gets presented to the user. It’s not necessarily how the data looks, but which data is presented. The view describes which data you see, not how you see it. It’s a subtle distinction.
>
> ...
>
> So, in our case, a “view” is the Python callback function for a particular URL, because that callback function describes which data is presented.
>
> ...
>
> Where does the “controller” fit in, then? In Django’s case, it’s probably the framework itself: the machinery that sends a request to the appropriate view, according to the Django URL configuration.

yeah, I totally agree with them in the case of `retrieve`. However, in the cases of something that modify (or delete) data, I can't agree with what they mention. Because generally I have implemented `view` to `modify` or `delete` as well. Which doesn't handle "which data is present" but "controlling data". In this sense, `view` (django says) is not called as a `view` but as `controller` I think.

Or am I implement `view` in wrong way? Please let me know the detail of django's "MTV".

Comment: Don't get too hung up on naming design patterns. Django works the way it works, we can describe it however we like.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah, but this question bothers me every day.

Answer (score 1):

For Django, there is no distinct border between View and Controller part, but there is a distinct border between View and Template part. For many other MVC frameworks, it's the other way around. That's why for others, technically MVCT frameworks, their type name is simplified to MVC (where view and template together form view) and for Django, it is MVT (where view and controller together form view). This is my understanding of that type naming scheme. But don't get too hung up on it. This is still very blurry and not true when you're using something like django-rest-framework.

Comment: Thank you for commenting and I agree with _But don't get too hung up on it_. However this question bothers me every night... Actually I'm also using django-rest-framework and in my opinion, it doesn't change a design pattern that pure django do. The only different thing is that django-rest-framework gives some convenient functions like `serializers` to make business logic loose coupled. (Serializers can have context, which means not stateless, so technically not completely loose coupled). I'm just courious about how django-rest-framework changes pattern? (And please correct me if I am wrong.)